# Accessing users languages using Graph API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, user-permissions

How do you access a user's languages using the Facebook GRAPH API? I don't see it anywhere in the permissions and I can't find it any other way. If a user lists that they speak Spanish or French, how can I find this?

Answer (score 8):

You can get the languages from https://graph.facebook.com/me .

If you are looking for user locale as @chacham15 mentions then its from locale variable . See  https://graph.facebook.com/harikt .

You can try http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me and see it in action.

Update :

The permission `user_likes` is need to access the languages array .

```
    [languages] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [id] => 105692839465644
                [name] => Malayalam
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [id] => 106059522759137
                [name] => English
            )

    )
```

Hope this solves your issue.

Comment: This is the data that the user himself inputted stating what languages he speaks, this may be null or empty

Comment: @chacham15 You are right if he is looking for locale. But I am not sure he is asking for languages also. "How do you access a user's languages using the Facebook GRAPH API?" . I have made the edit.

Comment: I am looking for what languages the user speaks, as listed on their profile. If it is accessible in /me, what is the variable called? It isn't languages? Do I have to call it separately from /me?

Comment: Ask for permission user_likes

Comment: `locale` is now deprecated as of V7.0....can we get it another way ?

Answer (score 2):

What I do is to check the user locale and I assume that he speaks that language, for example:

```js
$locale_f=$parsedJson->locale; 
$lang1=explode("_",$locale_f);
if ($lang1[0]=="es") $lang1="espagnol";
if ($lang1[0]=="en") $lang1="anglais";
if ($lang1[0]=="it") $lang1="italien";
if ($lang1[0]=="pt") $lang1="portugais";
if ($lang1[0]=="fr") $lang1="francais";
```

Answer (score 1):

You should display the language based on the locale variable which is part of the user table. You will get a value that is something like en_US (us english), en_GB (british english), or fr_FR (France french).